# Php project in eclipse

Tags: php

I have one project with is developed in Php and javascript. How to open the project in eclipse ide? I want to debug it.

Comment: File -> New -> PHP Project?.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Opening a project in Eclipse

Do you have access to the source code i.e. the PHP files?

If so, you should be able to open Eclipse and browse to the folder which contains the PHP files.

Eclipse uses the folder where the files are contained as the 'workspace' for the project.